# How to construct a sequence that has a subsequence convergent to every $k\in \Bbb{N}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

How to construct a sequence $\{a_{n}\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$, such that for every $k\in \Bbb{N}$, $\{a_{n}\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ has a subsequence convergent to $k$?

A subsequence is such as $2,4,6,...$ in $1,2,3,4,5...$ and we know that if a sequence converges to $L$ then every subsequence converges to $L$.

Perhaps I did not get the meaning of the question, but if a sequence is convergent, it has only one limit. How can we construct a sequence that converges to multiple limits?

Comment: The original sequence will not converge, but certain subsequences will.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\{1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,\dots\}$

Comment: Considering it's correct, how do you express such sequence?

Comment: To compute $a_n$, let $k=k(n)$ be the largest integer such that the triangular number $T_k=\frac {k(k+1)}2<n$, then $a_n=n-T_k$.  Closed formulas (in terms of the floor function) can be found, eg, here:  https://oeis.org/A002260  .  Note that the solution posted by @HagenvonEitzen is very similar (and has a cleaner closed form).

Answer (score 4):

Try $a_n=n-\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor^2$.

Answer (score 2):

The set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ is numerable, then there exists a bijective mapping $\varphi:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}$. By defining $$a_n=\varphi(n),\qquad n\in\mathbb{N}$$
we get a sequence such that for every real number $L$ there exist a subsequence $\{a_{n_{m}}\}_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $a_{n_{m}}\longrightarrow L$.